# OCI Python SDK to fetch instance unresponsive status

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to use Python SDK to fetch some information about Instances.
Is it possible to fetch instance status? I see often
[image]
What function could fetch problem like on the screenshot?
I was trying to search by that:

```
  "system_tags": {},
  "time_created": "2022-12-09T17:16:40.215000+00:00",
  "time_maintenance_reboot_due": null
}, {
```

but in this case maintenance_reboot is null.
thank you

```
  "system_tags": {},
  "time_created": "2022-12-09T17:16:40.215000+00:00",
  "time_maintenance_reboot_due": null
}, {
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `get_instance`API call? It should return your `Instance Reference` details that will include `lifecycleState` in the response field. `lifecycleState` will indicate the status of the instance.

Here are the links:

1. GetInstance API call (this has a Python SDK sample at the bottom) https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/Instance/GetInstance
2. Instance Reference - https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/Instance/

Comment: After life migration I see "lifecycle_state": "RUNNING", But the banner says that instance is unreachable and metrics are empty as well. I wondered if it's possible to fetch somehow this warning or empty metrics and restart automatically such instance.